# can't animate child component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, web-frontend, angular-animations

i have home component :

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Observable,Subscription,BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Session } from '../../ngrx/auth/auth.reducer'
import { User,Profile } from '../../ngrx/user/user.reducer'
import { resetUser } from '../../ngrx/user/user.actions'
import { RequestService, } from '../../services/request/request.service'
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service'
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bearer } from '../../decorators/transform.decorator'
import { sidebarAnimation } from '../../animations/sidebar.animation'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['./home.component.css'],
  animations: [sidebarAnimation]
})

export class HomeComponent {

  sidebarState = new BehaviorSubject<string>("hide")

  isSidebarIsntHidden = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)

  onSidebarStateChange = this.isSidebarIsntHidden.subscribe(
    state => state ? 
      this.toggleSidebarState(
        "hide"
      ) 
    : 
    this.toggleSidebarState(
      "show"
    )
  )

  switchSidebar(){
    this.isSidebarIsntHidden.next(
      !this.isSidebarIsntHidden.value
    )
  }
```

here it is the defention of sidebar Animation :

```
import { trigger,state,style,animate,transition } from '@angular/animations';

const animation  = transition('show <=> hide',[animate('0.3s')])

const toHideConfig = style({transform:`translate3d(-100%,0,0)`})

const toShowConfig = style({transform:`translate3d(0,0,0)`})

const show = state('show',toShowConfig)
const hide = state('hide',toHideConfig)

export const sidebarAnimation = trigger(
  'sidebarState',[
    show,
    hide,
    animation
  ]
)
```

and here it is in html file of home component where i want to give animation to sidebar component :

```
<div class="fullscreen flex flex-col z-10"> 

  <app-navbar 
    [user]="observableUser | async | getUser"
    (toggleSidebar)="switchSidebar()"
  />
    
  <div class="flex-1"> <!-- fetch result -->
        
  </div>

</div>

<app-fetch-error 
  *ngIf="(fetchState | async)?.error"
  [errorMessage]="(fetchState | async)?.error"
  (retry)="retry(fetchState.value.retryFunction)()"
/>

<app-loading [loading]="(fetchState | async)?.running" />

<app-sidebar [@sidebarState]="sidebarState | async"/>
```

the problem is sidebar component is not hidden when the first page appear, where it is supposed to be hidden. why can't i animate child component of home?

i've been trying to use query and animateChild, but the page goes to blank